# Add label in the middle of entire barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I need to place the label of the barplots in the middle of the entire plot.
Here is my data (called `subset`):

```
calb_all_mapped_reads_..mean calb_all_mapped_reads_..sd yeast_count probes method
1 70.9366666666667 5.84238250488046 Yeast_cells_10e5 No_probes B
2 2.46333333333333 0.892431136465629 Yeast_cells_10e3 No_probes B
3 99.3166666666667 0.0808290376865479 Yeast_cells_10e5 With_probes B
4 70.2666666666667 9.32056507585959 Yeast_cells_10e3 With_probes B
5 59.5866666666667 5.80288146814437 Yeast_cells_10e5 No_probes BT
6 10.44 4.73358215308449 Yeast_cells_10e3 No_probes BT
7 99.1233333333333 0.196299091524467 Yeast_cells_10e5 With_probes BT
8 90.7233333333333 4.26851652607007 Yeast_cells_10e3 With_probes BT
9 70.2766666666667 4.89424491963095 Yeast_cells_10e5 No_probes N
10 4.71 0.13076696830622 Yeast_cells_10e3 No_probes N
11 98.9366666666667 0.0450924975282305 Yeast_cells_10e5 With_probes N
12 83.8333333333333 1.07099642078456 Yeast_cells_10e3 With_probes N
13 61.3333333333333 4.52241454682489 Yeast_cells_10e5 No_probes T
14 2.37666666666667 0.234378611083293 Yeast_cells_10e3 No_probes T
15 99.1066666666667 0.338575447032611 Yeast_cells_10e5 With_probes T
16 71.9433333333333 2.93145583854394 Yeast_cells_10e3 With_probes T
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(subset, aes(x=method, y=calb_all_mapped_reads_..mean,label=round(calb_all_mapped_reads_..mean,1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="dodgerblue2" ) + facet_grid(probes ~ yeast_count)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=calb_all_mapped_reads_..mean-calb_all_mapped_reads_..sd,
                    ymax=calb_all_mapped_reads_..mean+calb_all_mapped_reads_..sd),
                    width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))+ylab("% of fungal reads")+
                    xlab("Enrichment method")+geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge(0.5))+theme_bw()
```

[image]
Now each label is in the middle of the corresponding bar, but I want it to be in the middle of the entire plot, so the upper left plot also look readable. Any help/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Try `facet_grid(probes ~ yeast_count, scales = "free")`

Comment: @PoGibas thanks, but it doesn't change the graph.

Comment: Set a dummy y value in the `geom_text`, such as 0.5

Comment: @camille you mean like this `geom_text(size = 3, y=0.5 ,position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`? This puts everything on the bottom, and gives a warning message.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed you were doing percentages as decimals. Use 50, not 0.5 and see what happens

Comment: @camille Thanks, it worked!